# Arguing that vs which is arguing that

Tags: meaning, grammar

1) Considering emerging evidence **arguing that** this virus is prevailing, Doctor  Carter ponders whether they should segregate this patient.

2) Considering emerging evidence **which is arguing that** this virus is prevailing, Doctor  Carter ponders whether they should segregate this patient.

---

Is sentence one is correct grammatically? And is sentence one' meaning is equal to sentence two's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is sentence one is correct grammatically?

Yes.

> And is sentence one' meaning is equal to sentence two's?

Yes.